# Java awt Checkbox constructors

Tags: java, awt

As I was reading thorough "Java the complete reference 9th" when I reached page 840 I've noticed something interesting. Checkbox class suports, among others, the following two constructors :

Checkbox(String str, **boolean** on, **CheckboxGroup** cbGroup) throws HeadlessException Checkbox(String str, **CheckboxGroup** cbGroup, **boolean** on) throws HeadlessException

The code behind these to looks like this :

```
public Checkbox(String label, boolean state, CheckboxGroup group)
throws HeadlessException {
    ...code...
}

public Checkbox(String label, CheckboxGroup group, boolean state)
throws HeadlessException {
    this(label, state, group);
}
```

As you can see the first is called by the second.. both seem to do the exact same thing, at least this is what I see. Why the second is needed ?

Comment: Both are doing the same thing, and they're not both needed, it's just in case some developers like to provide their arguments in another order.
But it's not much use cramming up on AWT, it's pretty obsolete these years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDK 1.0 introduced three constructors:

```
public Checkbox()
public Checkbox(String label)
public Checkbox(String label, CheckboxGroup group, boolean state)
```

JDK 1.1 wanted to add a different constructor which allowed to set the label and the state:

```
public Checkbox(String label, boolean state)
```

Now there is a good practice to use the same order of arguments in polymorphic functions. Instead of the constructor `Checkbox(String label, CheckboxGroup group, boolean state)` it would be better to have `Checkbox(String label, boolean state, CheckboxGroup group)`. Since the first variant could not be removed (as already published in JDK 1.0) the second, more coherent variant was simply added.